# .AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_data_yahoo'. I am getting this error only when I want to pass more than one symbol with loop

Tags: python-3.x, yfinance

This is my code with no error. But when I make the change as

```
symbol_list = ["INFY.NS", “TATAMOTORS.NS”]
```

in third line from bellow then I got the error

```
File "e:/PYTHON STOCK/test.py", line 19, in symbol_back_test
    pdr = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbol, period="2y", interval="1d")
  File "C:\Users\harek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5583, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_data_yahoo'
```

I cant understand what is going on. Why I cant pass more than one symbol through the loop. Can anybody please help.
Thanks.

```
import copy

import pandas as pd
import talib
import yfinance as yf

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option("display.width", None)
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

yf.pdr_override()


def symbol_back_test(symbol):
    global pdr
    pdr = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbol, period="2y", interval="1d")

    pdr["MA_10"] = talib.MA(pdr["Close"], timeperiod=10)
    pdr["MA_50"] = talib.MA(pdr["Close"], timeperiod=50)
    pdr["RSI_14"] = talib.RSI(pdr["Close"], timeperiod=14)

    position = None
    symbol_trades = []
    trade = {"Symbol": None, "Buy/Sell": None, "Entry": None, "Entry Date": None, "Exit": None, "Exit Date": None}

    for i in pdr.index[49:]:

        if pdr["MA_10"][i] > pdr["MA_50"][i] and pdr["RSI_14"][i] > 50 and position != "Buy":
            if trade["Symbol"] is not None:
                trade["Exit"] = pdr["Close"][i]
                trade["Exit Date"] = i
                symbol_trades.append(copy.deepcopy(trade))
            if position is not None:
                trade["Symbol"] = symbol
                trade["Buy/Sell"] = "Buy"
                trade["Entry"] = pdr["Close"][i]
                trade["Entry Date"] = i

            position = "Buy"
        if pdr["MA_10"][i] < pdr["MA_50"][i] and pdr["RSI_14"][i] < 50 and position != "Sell":
            if trade["Symbol"] is not None:
                trade["Exit"] = pdr["Close"][i]
                trade["Exit Date"] = i
                symbol_trades.append(copy.deepcopy(trade))
            if position is not None:
                trade["Symbol"] = symbol
                trade["Buy/Sell"] = "Sell"
                trade["Entry"] = pdr["Close"][i]
                trade["Entry Date"] = i

            print("Sell")
            position = "Sell"
    return symbol_trades


symbol_list = ["INFY.NS"]
for symbol in symbol_list:
    print(symbol_back_test(symbol))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this part of the code.

```
def symbol_back_test(symbol):
    global pdr <-- Why this is needed ?
    pdr = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbol, period="2y", interval="1d")
```

Firstly, you don't need the `global` declaration for `pdr` as its a module you are using. Now, the issue becomes this. You declared `pdr` as global. Now when the loop executes, first time all goes ok. But since you assign `pdr = pdr.get_data_yahoo(..`, the `pdr` variable now references a data frame and not the `pandas_datareader`. So in the 2nd loop execution, `pdr.get_data_yahoo` will raise an error, as `DataFrame` does not have a method like that.

You have to remove the global declaration and do not re-assign the module variable. For eg do like this.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as p_data_reader
def symbol_back_test(symbol):
   
    pdr = p_data_reader.get_data_yahoo(symbol, period="2y", interval="1d")
    ...
```

All should be fine.

Comment: Sir, I changed the coding as you asked to do. Now everything is ok. Really you are a knowledgeable person. Thank you Sir very much.

Comment: You can accept the answer and upvote it , if your problem was solved.